# Substitue a value inside a <tag>X</tag> and substitute with the value inside <anothertag>Y</anothertag>

Tags: notepad++

I have an xml file and inside it i have some tags, i need to copy what's inside of the tag from one and copy to another.

```
<xValue>100.0</xValue>
<xNumber>50.5</xNumber>
```

I have an xml file and inside ir i have some tags, i need to copy the tag from one and copy to another.

```
<xValue>100.0</xValue>
<xNumber>50.5</xNumber>
```

I need my `<xNumber>50.5</xNumber>` to have the value of my `<xValue>100.0</xValue>`, in the end it should be.

```
<xValue>100.0</xValue>
<xNumber>100.0</xNumber>
```

I've tried to replace `(?s)(?<=<xNumber>).+?(?=</xNumber>)` with `(?s)(?<=<xValue>).+?(?=</xValue>)` but it doesn't work, it does replace what's inside nNumber tag but it doesn't replace with whats inside xValue, it just copies the expression `(?s)(?<=<xValue>).+?(?=</xValue>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<xValue>(.+?)</xValue>\R<xNumber>\K.+?(?=</xNumber>)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<xValue>            # open tag
(.+?)               # group 1, the value to be duplicated
</xValue>           # close tag
\R                  # any kind of linebreak
<xNumber>           # open tag
\K                  # forget all we have seen until ths position
.+?                 # the value to be replaced
(?=</xNumber>)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a close teg after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all the help, i presented the example wrong because it didn't work for me, in my case for example value and number are in different lines and there're other tags between them, in this case, how can this be done?

Comment: Like this

<xValue>100.0</xValue><xExample>0.00</xExample><xExample>0.00</xExample><xExample>0.00</xExample><xExample>0.00</xExample><xNumber>50.5</xNumber>

Comment: @GuilhermeSouza: Change `\R` into `[\S\s]*?`. the regex becomes: `<xValue>(.+?)</xValue>[\S\s]*?<xNumber>\K.+?(?=</xNumber>)`

Comment: got it before reading your comment but thank you so much, worked with .*? thanks a lot man

Comment: @GuilhermeSouza: Be aware that using `.*?` will not work if tags are on different lines.